# General and basic question about convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Let $(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the following series converges
$$
S = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}
$$
It is known that for each $i$th the following series also converges
$$
S_i = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_{i,j}
$$
I want to prove neatly that the following holds 
$$
S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nS_i
$$

**My attempt**:
We know that for any $\epsilon_i>0$ there exists some $N_i$ such that for all $n\geq N_i$
$$
\left|\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}-S_i\right|\leq \epsilon_i
$$
for any any $i\geq1$. Also, we know that  for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists another $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}-S\right|\leq \epsilon
$$
Now, we want to show that for any $\tilde{\epsilon}>0$ there exists another $\tilde{N}$ such that for all $n\geq \tilde{N}$
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}-\sum_{i=1}^nS_i\right|\leq \tilde{\epsilon}
$$
But, we have that
\begin{align}
\left|S-\sum_{i=1}^nS_i\right| &\leq \left|S-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}\right|+\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}-\sum_{i=1}^nS_i\right|\\
&\leq \epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}-S_i\right|\\
&\leq \epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i \leq \epsilon+n\cdot\max \epsilon_i :=\tilde{\epsilon}
\end{align}

Comment: I think it should be $S_j$ in the second line, if the summand is $i$. Although the variable is mute, you're not changing the second index and the sum is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. (I am assuming that you meant $S_j$ in the second equation above. If not, take the 'transpose' of $a$ below.)

Let $a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i=j \\
-1, & i=j+1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = 1$ for all $n$, hence $S = 1$.

We have $S_j = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j} = 0$ for all $j$, and
hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n S_j = 0$.

The issue is that the $a_{ij}$ are not absolutely summable.